# Update datagridview rows in new column

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am parsing a website and I need to put some data in datagridview columns and rows. I add some data to rows in datagridview in column 0, then I want to put some new data in column 1 without losing old data. I try this below code but it just share my last value and all my rows are the same.

```
 foreach (HtmlNode pricesh in parse.SelectNodes("//div[@class='typeface-js realPrice']"))
        {
            string str = pricesh.InnerText;                
            int rowIndex = 0;
            for (rowIndex=0;rowIndex<=dataGridView1.RowCount-1;rowIndex++)
                dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value = str; 
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Add()` method will add a new row. You must get a reference to the row you want to manipulate and set it's Cell value.

You do not want to overwrite other columns with `DBNull.Value`, that will set them to null.

Define an index outside the loop, increment it inside the loop.
Do not loop over the rows within the foreach, just set the row at `rowIndex`.

Note this code is subject to `IndexOutOfRangeException` if you do not make sure the grid has at least as many rows as selected html nodes.

```
int rowIndex = 0;
    foreach (HtmlNode pricesh in parse.SelectNodes("//div[@class='typeface-js realPrice']"))
    {
        string str = pricesh.InnerText;                

        dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value = str; 

        rowIndex++;
    };
```

Comment: ok I do this, but i have 10 values. when i use "for" and rowindex++, it put just my last value in all the rows. how can i fix that?

Comment: Updated answer.